# Some (fundamental) questions and clarifications about Git

Tags: git

I'm looking into and learning the basics of distributed version control systems, specifically Git. After watching [Linus' Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8) about Git, I have a few questions that I don't fully understand. It's important to note that I am coming from an SVN, Windows-based background, and so all my questions are framed from that environment.

1. How is merging into other people's branches handled? That is, of Joe and Jane both branch from head/master, and Joe wants to merge the changes Jane's made in her branch, how is this done? To make my question more specific - if Joe is in Argentina and Jane is in Russia, how is this done? Does every Git branch come with a server capable of doing these things? Or is a central server still responsible for keeping track of all current branches and where they live? How does Git know where all of these (potentially thousands) of branches live? (Especially in a Windows environment!)
2. Linus talks about not having backups, saying this is unnecessary, as everyone has a copy of his code. But if he clones a repository, makes a few dozen lines of changes, commits, but never pushes...does he not lose all of his changes if his machine dies? I thought I understand this concept correctly (all commits are *local* until pushed), but he seems extremely blase about the issue, so I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

1) You will have to expose your repo such that peer-to-peer push / pull can be done using any one of the available transfer mechanisms ( ssh, git-daemon, etc.) In Git there is no real concept of server / client, but the general practice is to have a central repository that people push and pull to / from, much like the repo in SVN. Except that instead of the working copies, you have full repos on local as well. Being a DVCS, Git enables you directly collaborate with other people in your team and then push to the central repo. It will be very rare that you will not have such a central repo.

2) Linus must have been talking about backups for pushed code and not work in progress which reside on local repository, similar to how you would have changes in your working directory in SVN. Also note that he must have been talking **in context of Linux code**, which has hundreds of collaborators and hence he must have mentioned that they need not worry about backups of the repository since everyone has a copy of it. But of course, you can potentially lose your local changes / commits unless you have pushed.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are [multiple protocols](http://book.git-scm.com/7_transfer_protocols.html) git can use to transfer data between repositories:

   - Dumb HTTP - The client literally just downloads the required git object files, so any http server works.  However, this wastes bandwidth.
   - [Smart HTTP](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html)
   - Fetch Pack over SSH
   - Fetch Pack over git

The last three are all "smart", in that client and server collaborate to avoid transferring unnecessary data.

You can also use [git bundle](http://progit.org/2010/03/10/bundles.html) to export a binary with your changes, and then manually transfer it to someone else's computer.

Your repo doesn't need to know where all the thousands of other branches are.  Typically, you will add the few (or one) that you push or pull to/from as a [remote](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-remote).  That's basically a shortcut for a repository URL.  However, you can still push and pull from other URLs.

Regardless of how you fetch the data, you eventually use [git merge](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-merge) to merge it in.

2. Yes, Linus means he doesn't need backups of things he's already pushed.  Presumably (if he really doesn't have backups), he commits and pushes often.  You shouldn't take him too literally, as he is usually going for dramatic effect in his public statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a short answer. Lets start with 2). Yes you would lose data. He meant you dont need backups in a traditional sense (make copies of your full directory everytime). If you push its 'backed up'. If you didnt you iwll lose only the data since last push. Pushes are not the same as copy/paste.

1) How is merging into other people's branches handled?

Essentially you have a git repository on your computer, either a cloned repo or a brand new one. Then you either need a remote location were you can push (you simply create a 'bare' repository then push to it) or you must have read access for other people to your files  (perhaps on lan but pushing to a server is more traditional). With this bare repo or read access for others they can 'pull' your code into their repo and you can do the same. You can pull from anyone in any order even if the people dont know eachother and pulled from ppl you dont know about. The magic in git will figure out where to put everything and not merge something twice. Its pretty good at recognizing conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

1) The merging is handled locally - servers do little more than enforcing linear timeline.

In order to merge local with remote, your Joe will 'git pull' Jane's branch (over any of the supported protocols - some as simple as filesystem access, some more confusing like git+ssh), resolve any conflicts, and then potentially push his changes to the master (if he has write permissions there) or, publish it for Jane to get. If Jane didn't change anything in the meantime, she can git pull Joe's post-merge code without any manual merging.

How does it know - it doesn't, you tell it where the remote branches are. There are hosting providers for git (github.com), you can roll your own on your webserver, and tell Joe/Jane the url via any means

2) Backups are rarely more often than daily. Linus presumably pushes more often than backs up - in fact, I use git as backup for my code regardless - with multiple remotes, I have a remote for my own code that is automatically pushed after each meaningful commit.